# How to prevent a character from being created again if it already exists? It must prevent creating characters through the importer and the form

Tags: java, arrays, spring, maven, javabeans

The project aim is to create and organize data for a tv show.

In this project, a user can import and enter data directly. The data is already deployed in production and active.

You have to prevent a character from being created again if it already exists (i.e: the name is already taken). It must prevent creating characters through the importer and the form.

If the character is created with the form, it must show an error message following the same format that is already in place.

From my understanding the code should:

1. Use the data entered and scan it through column 1 (characters name) and with a while loop (maybe?) see if it already exists.
2. If it does exist, the code should output: "Error this character exists"
3. If it the data entered doesn't exists then it would add it onto the existing data.

So far I've coded the following to read the csv file which works:

Edit: Thanks to Sir Pleft I got it working with the following code:

```
package com.openCSV.mavenproject;

import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;
import com.opencsv.bean.StatefulBeanToCsv;
import com.opencsv.bean.StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String inputName = "John"; //this is your input
        
        String file = "/Users/apple/eclipse-workspace/Test/data/characters.csv";
        
    //Convert CSV to bean

        List<Character> characters = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader(file))
                .withType(Character.class)
                .withSkipLines(1)
                .build()
                .parse();

        characters.forEach(System.out::println);

        boolean anyMatch = characters.stream().anyMatch(character -> character.getName().equals(inputName));

        if (anyMatch) {
            System.out.println("Error this character exists");
        } else {
            Character character = new Character();
            character.setName(inputName);
            characters.add(character);
            Writer writer = new FileWriter(file);
            StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
            beanToCsv.write(characters);
            writer.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Now my issue is when I run the above code, I get the error message below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing CSV line: 1036, values: 

    at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:376)
    at com.openCSV.mavenproject.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvMalformedLineException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text: [
]
    at com.opencsv.CSVReader.readNext(CSVReader.java:355)
    at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.submitAllBeans(CsvToBean.java:296)
    at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean.parse(CsvToBean.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

It specifies line 1036, however my CSV file is only up to line 1035

So I think the program is working? and reaching the end of my csv and then doesn't know what to do.

How would I edit my code so that it breaks after the csv file finishes?

Comment: Is this a Spring project? You have tagged it as but your shared code is plain java. Moreover can you add third party dependencies? Looks like OpenCSV library could help you greatly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is maven then you can add OpenCSV library to help you

Add in your `pom.xml` the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create the `Character` class which will hold one line of your CSV. For convenience I have added only the `name` and `description` fields, you can either add the others too or you can just leave the `name` field for your purposes.

```
public class Character {

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private String name;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

And here is some code that performs what you are asking: Read through the csv file and if it finds a name that matches the given input it prints an error else it adds it to the csv file.

```
String inputName = "John"; //this is your input

List<Character> characters = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new FileReader("D:\\characters.csv"))
        .withType(Character.class)
        .withSkipLines(1)
        .build()
        .parse();

characters.forEach(System.out::println);

boolean anyMatch = characters.stream().anyMatch(character -> character.getName().equals(inputName));

if (anyMatch) {
    System.out.println("Error this character exists");
} else {
    Character character = new Character();
    character.setName(inputName);
    characters.add(character);
    Writer writer = new FileWriter("D:\\characters.csv");
    StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
    beanToCsv.write(characters);
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this pleft. What do you mean by creating Character class to 'hold on line of your CSV'. What is the use of this? Also would I combine the last section of code you added underneath my code I've written for reading the csv?

Comment: Each one line in your csv file is a Character with a name a description, biography etc. My code maps each line of your csv to a Character object. My code in the answer is standalone it is not meant to be combined with yours. It works as is and does exactly what you have described. You can try it on your own to see what I mean.

Comment: any ideas? Were you able to run the code successfully?

Comment: LEGEND @pleft I finally got the code working and it prints the error message if I put a name that already exists in the inputName string! Only weird thing is the console prints all the csv  as 'com.openCSV.mavenproject.Character@75828a0f' in the console when parsing through the name. I would upvote your answer but I ned 15 reps.. thanks again!

Comment: Your csv has an error at the end it is missing a “ (double quote). That’s why you get the error. Btw you edited your question and completely removed the original content and replaced it with the answer’s code. This is going to be confusing. It would be better if you restored the original content and appended in the end anything new e.g the new error stacktrace as an update.